# Read-only anonymous access to Azure Container registry

Tags: azure-container-registry

Is there a way to configure an Azure Container Registry (managed) to support anonymous access? The containers in my registry are boring (Ubuntu + some packages) and are used for building on Travis CI.

At the moment, the approach I'm planning to take is to create a Service Principal and just embed the key in my .travis.yml, effectively "leaking" it.

Travis's [secret environment variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml) feature has a sensible default of not sharing encrypted variables with builds done in response to a pull request, but for my purposes, I do want pull requests to be able to pull the images. Thus, it doesn't appear applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Configuring an Azure Container Registry for Read-Only Anonymous Pull Access

Setting up your Azure Container Registry (ACR) [for public read-only access (unauthenticated anonymous pull access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/anonymous-pull-access) is a feature that users can optionally enable on ACR Registries. Once enabled, any internet user can pull content from within the registry without needing to authenticate.

This feature is currently available as a preview feature [for Standard and Premium SKU registries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-skus).

---

### Enabling Anonymous Access

To [enable anonymous access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/anonymous-pull-access#enable-anonymous-pull-access) on an existing registry, update a registry using the `az acr update` command and pass the `--anonymous-pull-enabled` parameter. By default, anonymous pull is disabled in the registry.

```
az acr update --name myregistry --anonymous-pull-enabled
```

---

### Disabling Anonymous Access

Disable anonymous pull access on an existing registry by setting `--anonymous-pull-enabled` to false.

```
az acr update --name myregistry --anonymous-pull-enabled false
```

Answer (score 0):

ACR currently does not support anonymous access. You can find the roadmap and issues here - https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/master/docs/acr-roadmap.md

Comment: I've raised a feature request on the [Azure User Voice site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/903958-azure-container-registry/suggestions/32517127-enable-anonymous-access-to-registries) for this.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2019, read-only/anonymous access is in public preview. You need to contact the ACR team to have it enabled. From the [feature request's completion notes](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/903958-azure-container-registry/suggestions/32517127-enable-anonymous-access-to-registries):

> Anonymous (referred to as public registries) are now supported for preview customers. Preview is for two reasons:
>
> - Most customers want only a subset of their registry to be anonymous. We need to finish the repo-permissions feature (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/903958-azure-container-registry/suggestions/31655977-configure-permissions-at-a-repository-level) to enable anonymous repos.
> - To support the range of customers, from small to large, we’re working on a new consumption based billing tier. This way small use-case customers don’t have to pay for a premium registry, and large customers can get the scaling they need, based on their use.
>
> To enable public repos, please contact acrsup@microsoft.com.
> Once repo permissions and the new billing tier are complete, we’ll have this directly available in the portal and cli.
> Until the new pricing tier is available, public repos will be limited to standard and premium tiers.